# ASP.NET Core Route not working

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core-mvc

The Routers are configured this way:

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "api",
        template: "api/{action}/{id?}");
});

app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "spa-fallback",
        template: "{*url}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index"});
});
```

The controller I action I am trying to request looks like this:
// GET api/values/5

```
[HttpGet("{id}")]
public string Get(int id)
{
    return "value" + id;
}
```

When I request http://localhost:54057/api/values/get, I get back "value0".

When I request http://localhost:54057/api/values/get, I get back "value0".

When I request http://localhost:54057/api/values/get/5, I get back a 404 Not Found.

Are my routes configured incorrectly, or why is that that the "id" parameter is not passed from the URL to the controller action?

Comment: [ASP.NET Routing Debugger](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/13/url-routing-debugger.aspx/) FTW!

Comment: Try `{id:int}`. And then in the method, `return "value " + id.ToString();`

Comment: In your examples you don't need to include "/get" at the end of the URL. The URL should just be "/api/values/5", and if the request type is a "get" it will hit that action properly (with the change suggested in an answer below).

Answer (score 2):

Define the full route, SPA overrides the default MVC routing

```
        [HttpGet("api/[controller]/[action]/{id}")]
        public IActionResult Get(int id)
        {
            return ...;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to specify controller and not a an action. Your route should be defined as:

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "api",
        template: "api/{controller}/{id?}"); <-- Note the change here
});

app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "spa-fallback",
        template: "{*url}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index"});
});
```

The reason you were getting the results when no parameter was specified was most probably due to the fallback route being called. If you want to know which route is being invoked, have a look at this article on [Route Debugging](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2013/04/04/debugging-asp-net-web-api-with-route-debugger/).

Comment: That debugging package does not seem to work with core

Comment: You can put MapRoute() inside the 1st UseMvc().