# @Html.ActionLink with an id for the link not working

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages

When I click on the edit link, I get a page not found error. I can see the url when I hover over the edit link as `/editprofile/Edit/0E...` but should it be `/editprofile/Edit/id=0E...` and that is why I get page not found. Here is my HtmlAction link for edit:

```
<td>
    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.Id }, new {id = "@Id"}) 
</td>
```

Comment: With a standard route of `{controller}/{action}/{id}`, it is `/editprofile/Edit/0E` that is correct, so `ActionLink` is probably working as it should. `/editprofile/Edit/id=0E` is not even valid due to the absence of the `?`. `/editprofile/Edit?id=0E` would be a valid URL per se, but it would be weird. How do your routes look like?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by routes exactly? I know that you can put a @page {id:int} at the top of the edit page but I don't think that would solve the problem, would it?

Comment: Here is my route app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });

Comment: That is a normal route, and `/editprofile/Edit/0E` correctly matches it. [Debug your routes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39668039/asp-net-core-route-not-working#comment66637791_39668039).